# Stacking JSON results in one file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am new to Python and struggling with basic tasks. Is there an easy way to stack columns from JSON outcome results in one file? I have done the following: using the predefined function I extract one JSON file per row/search and then I extract the fields I am interested in like this:

```
No = data[1,0]
Search = function(data[1,1])
Res1 = Search['webPages']['value'][0]['snippet']
Res2 = Search['webPages']['value'][1]['snippet']
```

What I want to do is to store 3 values: *No*, *Res1*, *Res2* in 3 columns per row and loop the search over to create rows (if I have 100 searches, my final outcome should be an array of 100 x 3).
Hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used panda dataframes instead:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['No','Res1','Res2'], index=range(1,100))

for x in range(1,100):
    No = data[1,0]
    Search = function(data[1,1])
    Res1 = Search['webPages']['value'][0]['snippet']
    Res2 = Search['webPages']['value'][1]['snippet']
    DF.loc[x] = [No, Res1, Res2, Res3]
```